# Error generating classes for schema 'onvif'

Tags: c#, xsd, onvif

I'm currently trying to generate classes from a .xsd file that is accessible from:
https://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd

I saved that .xsd file in a folder on my computer.

I opened a Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 as administrator.

I went under C:...\myFolder .

I then used the `xsd /c onvif.xsd` command to create my classes/get a .cs file, but i keep getting a bunch of warnings and the error:

> Error: Error generating classes for schema 'onvif'.
>
> - The datatype 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2:FilterType' is missing.

As anyone ever had that error?

How do i get rid of it?

In the onvif.xsd file, there's a reference to the http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2.xsd file...
[image: img0]

If i look a bit further, i can see that the `wsnt` "namespace" is used to get `FilterType` a couple of times...

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

and, when i look into the http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2.xsd file, I can see that the datatype `FilterType` apearing in my error is there...

[image: img3]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the b-2.xsd schema.  You can find it here:  http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2.xsd